# Running an XP install on a physical disk on vmware

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive, vmware-workstation

I have a solution I need to solve using XP, I have VMWare Workstation on my Win7 laptop - can I use an external hard disk that has an XP install on it, rather than having to install XP on a vmx ?
I used to use Shapeshifter (a mac emulator on the amiga!) which could do this...

Comment: which vmware version you are using?this may help u https://communities.vmware.com/thread/117671?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: 10 - the 30 day trial version. Thanks, I'll have a look!